# error when trying to set multiple list validation formulas inside my custom list Validation Settings

Tags: 2013, list, development, validation, validation-list-items

I want to add these validations to my list:-

1. if the status= "Invoiced", then user must enter a value inside the "Customer Invoice Date".
2. if the status = "Paid", then the user must enter a value inside the "Customer Paid Date"

now i tried addign these formulas inside my list validation:

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF(Status="Paid",IF([Customer Paid Date ]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

but i got an error:-

> The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula
>   for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing
>   column.

Now if i add each formula alone,they will work, but having them together will not work.. so is there a way i can add multiple validation for my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR to combine the two formulas.

You can try that:

```
=OR(IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE), IF(Status="Paid",IF([Customer Paid Date ]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```

If it doesn't work, you can also use your formula:

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF(Status="Paid",IF([Customer Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

And when you type the formula, DO NOT copy the formula and paste it, just type it one by one manually.

Reference:
[same thread in TechNet forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d10df169-84d7-491c-b3d0-c05bf91bee5c/unable-to-add-multiple-list-validation-formulas?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: i tried your formula and it got saved successfully, but both checks are not being applied, as i am able to change the status to "Paid" or to "Invoiced", while leaving the related fields empty, without getting any messages...

Comment: Please test your original formula again, and when you type the formula, DO NOT copy the formula and paste it, just type it one by one manually

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one formula. You have to combine the two formulas so that combined they return a true or false.

```
=AND( firstCondition, secondCondition )
```

Both must return true for the AND to return true.

```
=AND( IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),
IF(Status="Paid",IF([Customer Paid Date ]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE) )
```

But I think what you want is this:

```
=OR(IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),  FALSE  ),
    IF(Status="Paid",IF([Customer Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),  FALSE  ))
```

as you want Invoiced and a date or Paid and a date. If either is true, then the column validates.

Here's a shorter and cleaner version using just AND's and OR's:

```
=OR( AND(Status="Invoiced",[Customer Invoiced Date]<>"" ), 
     AND(Status="Paid",[Customer Invoiced Date]<>"" )
   )
```

And if the item is OK if Status and both dates are blank then:

```
=OR( AND(Status="Invoiced",[Customer Invoiced Date]<>"" ), 
     AND(Status="Paid",[Customer Invoiced Date]<>"" ),
     AND(Status="",[Customer Invoiced Date]="",[Customer Invoiced Date]="" )
   )
```

Comment: thanks for answer, now i tried your formula, and it got saved successfully without errors,, but i am able to save an item which have status= Paid, and its Customer Paid Date is emty.. and same applies to the Invoiced status

Comment: The "OR" fixed the issue you asked about. There's an error in your logic. The final "TRUE" of each outer IF should be "FALSE". I edited the above example.